# How to handle close signal from unity in visual c++

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine, signals

I'm developing an Unity 3D application in C#. From the Unity script I open a third party console application. Then I close the third party console application by using the `CloseMainWindow` method.
In the third party application, written in C++, I want to handle the closing signal to dispose some resources.
I tried to put this in my console application:

```
BOOL WINAPI consoleHandler(DWORD signal) {
    if (signal == CTRL_C_EVENT)
        printf("Ctrl-C handled\n");
    if (signal == CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT)
        printf("End task handled\n");
    //dispose resources
    return TRUE;
}
```

and in the `main` I put:

```
if (!SetConsoleCtrlHandler(consoleHandler, TRUE)) {
        printf("\nERROR: Could not set control handler");
        return 0;
    }
```

this handler works if I close the console application from the "X" button on the console window, but it does nothing when I close the console application from the Unity script. How can I do? Thank You very much.

Comment: I think you need use GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent WinAPI function instead of CloseMainWindow